# difference between FBA and SAML based authentication?

Tags: sharepoint

we have to create SharePoint extranet sites by using SharePoint foundation 2010 for clients.we have to use Claims based authentication.So which one is better FBA or SAML authentication.

please tell me which one is better what are the advantages and disadvantages are there for both.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with SAML but from what I can tell, you would need an authentication provider to use SAML. FBA is based on the user providing a username and password which requires no infrastructure. It is always nicer for the end user if they don't have to bother with providing credentials, but what are the requirements that you have, and do you have the ability to use an authentication provider?